# ECDH can be used for Key Agreement(KA) as per ECIES specification?

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-exchange, ecies

I want to implement a library to provide ECIES (Elliptical Curve Integrated Encryption Standard). We could see DH can be used as KA function for ECIES. I want to know specifically the ECDH (Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman) function can be used for KA (Key Agreement) functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Diffie-Hellman is a specific form of key agreement, and any key agreement can be used for IES. Of course ECIES normally uses ECDH - ECIES cannot use the normal DH scheme, as it doesn't use Elliptic Curves.